# Multiple return types in Numpy type annotations

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy

Numpy's recent version 1.20 [includes type annotations](https://numpy.org/neps/roadmap.html#type-annotations). This is great, and tools like mypy, instead of complaining about Numpy lacking type information now complain about your code.

This trivial example calculates the centroid of m points of n dimensions that will always return a point:

```
from numpy import ndarray
def centroid(points: ndarray) -> ndarray:
    return points.mean(axis=0)
```

Before Numpy 1.20, mypy complained with `Skipping analyzing numpy`. Now it says

> Mypy: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[number[Any], ndarray]", expected "ndarray")

because `mean()` may return a number or an array, but only an array is expected as the return value of `centroid()`.

The warning can be avoided without adding execution time with

```
    return cast(ndarray, points.mean(axis=0))
```

or simply

```
    return points.mean(axis=0)       # type: ignore
```

Is there a better method without incurring in additional computations?

Comment: I don't think there's currently a better way - but note that using `cast` won't result in any extra computations